# Textarea fill parent container

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get my textarea to fill the full width of the div it is wrapped in, but even when using `width:100%` and `display:block` . At the start it does appear to be stretched but when it is focused it drops down again. i just can't seem to be able to have it stretch the full width when a user goes to type into it.

Really head frying, because I cant set it to be a specific width, as the wrapper width varies with monitor size.

any ideas?

Comment: Can you attach some code or a fiddle, so we can see for ourselves?

Comment: Do you have a *focus* psuedo-selector where the CSS properties are changed? That could be the cause of your issue.

Comment: yeah the parent container didnt have a width, or height set, thats where the problem came from. thanks for the help

Comment: so your problem has been solved now? confusing.

Comment: yeah, a bit of derp on my part. i didnt realise the parent container had to have a specific width set for the textarea to fill it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure your parent div has a height and width set. Otherwise `height: 100%` and `width: 100%` will not work.

See here for example:
http://jsfiddle.net/wXs92/